# Why custom.js only error in homepage, in several page is working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some trouble with my wordpress (https://dev.smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/). When I open console, the result like in below.

```
custom.js?ver=5.4.1:542 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectmenu is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=5.4.1:542)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

And when I click search button, the button is not showing and not working. But when I navigate to https://dev.smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/?page_id=58 all error in above it's clear and search button are working properly.

My Question is : What Should I Do and Have any Idea to Fix It ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`.selectmenu()` is one of the functions that exist within Jquery-UI**, and it exists to modify the native browser select. In the **first provided URL you are using a form with select which is invoking this function** (You don't have a form in the second provided URL), **it seems `jquery-ui.js` do not exist in your scripts so it will throw an error**. Try to add it with WordPress widgets or manually through your HTML like this (you should add v1.11 or above):

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

or

<script src="https://dev.smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/selectmenu.min.js?ver=1.11.4"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks to answer my question, I have done my trouble

Answer (score 0):

**the problem is your library missing selectmenu function**

just include missing library :

> https://dev.smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/selectmenu.min.js?ver=1.11.4

like:

```
<script src="https://dev.smanegeri1sindang.sch.id/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/selectmenu.min.js?ver=1.11.4"></script>
```

Comment: It's same problem, but with your question I have idea to fix it. Thanks for advice

Comment: i prefer to add the script from my answer because it's already exists on your server and it will not create any conflicts with other resources